# single level variable in ggplot2::geom_tile

Tags: r, plot

I've got a data frame with three variables, `location`, `price`, and `varname`.

I'd like to use ggplot2's `geom_tile` to make a heat map of sorts. This plot almost looks like a bar chart, but I prefer `geom_tile` because I like the values, big or small, to be allocated the same amount of physical space on the plot.  My code almost gets me there.

The first problem's that I can't format the plot so to get rid of all the white space to the left and right of my pseudo-bar. The second problem's that I can't remove the `Price` legend below the plot, because I'd like `Price` only to feature in the legend above the plot.

Thanks for any help!

Starting point (`df`):

```
df <- data.frame(location=c("AZ","MO","ID","MI"),price=c(1380.45677,1745.1245,12.45652,1630.65341),varname=c("price","price","price","price"))
```

Current code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(varname,location, width=.2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = price),colour = "white") + geom_text(aes(label = round(price, 3))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "ivory1", high = "green") +
  theme_classic() + labs(x = "", y = "") + theme(legend.position = "none") + ggtitle("Price")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't set the width to 0.2.
2. Use `theme` to disable the labels and ticks.
3. You might want to use `coord_equal` to get nice proportions (i.e. squares). `expand = FALSE` gets rid of all white space.

.

```
ggplot(df, aes(varname, location)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = price), colour = "white") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = round(price, 3))) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "ivory1", high = "green") +
    theme_classic() + labs(x = "", y = "") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
    ggtitle("Price") + 
    coord_equal(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]